Does Berry phase $2\pi n$ mean anything?
Today I tried computing the Berry phase for some time periodic system evolving under the Schrodinger equation, and got the following result - upon completing a period, the $n$th eigenstate will acquire a phase of $2\pi n$.
Naively, this means that nothing happens - if I measure the eigenstate in the beginning and at the end, I'll get the exact same result. But something did seem to happen here in terms of winding numbers - it seems like the $n$th eigenstate "rotates" $n$ times around itself throughout the period, even though you cannot really measure this.
Does such a result have any physical meaning? Or does it make no sense to talk about such a monodromy in this context?
Thanks in advance.

The global phase of a single state is irrelevant. In this case, since during a period all states acquire a $2\pi n$ pase, the relative phases between states are also irrelevant since they are always multiples of $2\pi$. If that weren't the case, the superposition of quantum states would present an observable difference due to the relative phase between terms.

Agreed, there really is no way to measure a relative phase under this evolution. The question is whether the winding itself of the states (which does not affect the relative phase) has any interpretable meaning in this context.

You can think of it as the state rotating, similarly to how a single stationary state "rotates" every $2\pi/\omega$, even though that effect is also not measurable.

Look up Thouless charge pump if you don't already know what it is.  Classic example of integer Berry phase having some actual meaning.  But like others have said, you won't be able to tell zero from $2\pi$ just looking at initial and final states.  You have to watch the winding process to know something has happened.
